# How to show this map is open?

Tags: quotient-spaces, open-map

Let $f$ be the canonical quotient map of $\mathbb R^{n+1} - \{0\}$ onto $\mathbb R P^n$. Restrict $f$ to the hyperplane $H$ away from zero, so let $g = f|H$. Then I want to show that $g$ is a homeomorphism. It is easy to check that $g$ is bijective and continuous. Also easy to show that $f$ is an open mapping.

But how to show that $g$ is an open mapping?

Comment: Maybe use some concrete parametrization for H? For example let $H=\{(\mathbf{x}, 1)| \mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^n\}$ that is the hyperplane with the $(n+1)$-th coordinate equaling 1. And let $p: \Bbb{R}^{n+1}\sim \{0\} \rightarrow H$ be the projection from $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\sim \{0\}$ to it: $p((\mathbf{x}, y)) = (\mathbf{x}/y, 1)$. Then for any open set $G$ in $H$, $p^{-1}(G)$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\sim \{0\}$. And $p^{-1}(G) = f^{-1}(g(G))$. By definition of $\Bbb{R}P^n$, $g(G)$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many such hyperplanes. Okay, let us pick one. If $g$ were a homeomorphism, we would get a homeomorphism $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb RP^n$. But this cannot exist.